# How can I compose the following problem into a dynamic algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

let's say I want to algorithmic calculate the total amount to be invested independently from INCOME, LIVING EXPENSES or EMERGENCY FUND however if some of them gets bigger than any of them, it will result in negative . however I dont need to reach 0 instead split balance into two groups `0/100`, `20/80`, plus 50-100 from balance if emergency fund isnt filled .

so, if the emergency fund is less than the emergency fund target, then some money goes into group a, some money goes into group b, and some money goes into the emergency fund.  if the emergency fund is equal to or greater than the emergency fund target, then some money goes into group a, and some money goes into group b.

```py
income = 1250 
expenses = 75
emergency_fund = 500
emergency_fund_target = expenses * 3

balance = income - expenses

value = None

output = balance if balance > 0.0 else 0.0

if emergency_fund_target > emergency_fund:
    value = output
else:
    value = 0 # it should skip the emergency fund , and only allocate from 0 to 100% from output

print(value)
```

[image: balance]